# Signed result of subtracted unsigned integers?

Tags: c++, unsigned, subtraction

I'm trying to create a class analagous to `vector<string>` and another class analagous to its iterators (purely as an exercise from C++ Primer (exercise 14.28 for those interested)). The iterator class works by having a `vector<string>::size_type` member (called `curr`) to represent an index of the vector. I did not wish to paste the entire works because it's quite long, but I've reached some level of confusion when trying to define my own subtraction operator for the iterators. Ultimately it should work like subtracting two iterators, and produce a negative value if necessary. I have the function defined like this:

```
??? operator-(const iterator& lhs, const iterator& rhs){
    return (lhs.curr - rhs.curr);
}
```

Alternatively, another version of my confusion;

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    vector<string>::size_type x = 5, y = 3;

    ??? z = (y-x); //what should ??? be if I want -2?

    cout << z;

}
```

`(y-x)` is `-2` but of course wraps back around to `4294967294` since it is a 32-bit unsigned expression, before storing it in z. I can't figure out how to define my return type so that if rhs (y) is further along in the sequence than lhs (x), the correct negative value is returned (stored in z).

I thought `vector<string>::difference_type` might do that trick but I found out that `size_type` represents a 32-bit unsigned integer while `difference_type` represents a 32-bit signed integer, so there will be an error of wrapping around with signed integers which is undefined behaviour - even though on my computer it produces the correct result. I could `static_cast` everything to `long long int` and return a `long long int` but I feel that would be a bit too brute forced.

Comment: [What type should I use for iterator difference to eliminate “possible loss of data” warnings?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3941660/995714)

Comment: Were you tried 'auto' or you don't want to ?

Comment: @RichardGeorge `auto` would just set `z` as unsigned, which isn't desired.

Comment: To handle all possible result ranges (from `[-INT_MAX; INT_MAX]`), you can't use (`signed`/`unsigned`) `int`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct type to use is indeed `vector<string>::difference_type`. You can easily implement iterator subtraction like this:

```
difference_type operator- (const iterator &lhs, const iterator &rhs)
{
  if (rhs.curr >= lhs.curr) return static_cast<difference_type>(rhs - lhs);
  else return - static_cast<difference_type>(lhs - rhs);
}
```

Real implementations of the standard library probably don't necessarily need to do that, since they are usually targeted at a particular compiler and can use internal knowledge of how the compiler handles implementation-defined behaviour such as the result of converting an unsigned value to a signed type when outside of the signed range.

Comment: @simplicisveritatis Not really. The result of subtracting two unsigned numbers is unsigned, `abs()` won't help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But what if `rhs` (or `y`) was `4000000000` and `lhs` (or `x`) was say, `3`. Then the answer I get back (on my machine) is 294967299 because of signed integer overflow, but I would have wanted the answer 3999999997.

Comment: Hmm, actually now that I've thought a little bit more. `difference_type` might be _guaranteed_ to hold the difference between two iterators (although I can't find a quote for that) meaning vector sizes cannot go larger than 2^31 despite `size_type` being large enough to hold 2^32. So I would never have to worry or be expected to worry about cases where `curr` is larger than 2^31. So thanks.

Comment: There's no undefined behavior involved.  The difference between two values of unsigned type is also unsigned, then it is cast.  There might be modular reduction in the subtraction step, but that's well-defined.  There can't be "overflow" during a cast -- if the value isn't representable in the destination type then the result is implementation-defined.  That might not be good enough, but it is not undefined behavior.